# Detecting multiple installations of the same application

Tags: c#, .net

Writing into `registry` while installing an app can detect further installation on the same system ,I have tried and tested the same but,

> is there any method to restrict installing more than three times or
>   above the same software on different systems?

Is there any apt method to do that at development scenario?

Thanks

Comment: This is a licensing thing I presume? You can create a machine ID (google for it) and use that to send a call to a WCF service. Store the ID in a database. That said, a proper licensing implementation can be quite hard, so I would recommend using a standard package for it.

Comment: thank you ,@atlaste But there is limitation for online databases to store the details in database.Yes its like licensing

Comment: there are no such limitations; it's a simple binary blob you store along with the user/order ID or something like that.

Comment: but what if database is cleared and fresh backup of DB is used?

Comment: Then you do something bad and should stop doing that. That's not how you handle databases

Comment: The cleanest implementation that causes the least problems for your *genuine* customers is to tell them "you can install this on up to 3 machines" and if you discover they're exceeding this limit, you rely on contracts and the law. Anything you do beyond this will a) not deter the people who are just going to rip you off anyway and b) may cause unforeseen issues for your genuine customers.

Comment: thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever for your time,but how come i know that they are using more than three times.Sorry if the question is irrelevant

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Unfortunately experience has shown that some customers aren't really polite with that, so it makes sense to gather the data. That said, even though we do gather the data, the main action we take is just to ask some polite questions when people are abusing our good faith. It's a bit of a balance...